# VM Server not able to join domain host in another VM domain controller

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

I set up two WM on my win 8 computer using VMware workstation, both running window server 2012 R2 operating system, one serves as a domain controller, DNS server and DHCP server, the other one servers as a client who is supposed to join the domain created by the DC, here is what I did :
1.On the DC machine, install AD, DNS, DHCP, then promoted a domain controller
2.On the Client machine, try to join to the domain I created, but cannot work, the error message shows, domain controller cannot be contacted, DNS name does not exist.

Here are some information I have and things I've already tried and did not work, so please finish reading all and do not give me things I've already known.
1.For both VM the network adapter is Bridged mode; the host machine sits on a cooperate domain.
2.Firewall for both VM have been turn off, both machines can ping each other and get response.
3.I was able to use nslookup domain.com on the client machine to find the address of the DNS server on the Domain Controller 
4.In the client VM, I changed setting in the Internet Protocal Version 4, and set preferred DNS server to point to the DNS server ip in my Domain Controller, and reboot.

Did I missing anything ?

Comment: Can you try and connect to the C drive on the DC from the client. Connect by running "\\<DC-name>\c$". It should prompt for credentials. Let me know if you can authenticate in this way. If getting into the DCs C drive doesn't work, try it the other way and see if you can hit the clients C drive.